# Use wildcard in path for list.files

Tags: r

I need to use wildcard in my path, but somehow this is not recognised by R. The path is correct.  Any idea why it fails?

```
 list.files(path = paste0("./Unzipped/",input_files[1],"/Variants/*/"), pattern = "tsv$")
 character(0)
```

File in located here:

```
"./Unzipped/FolderLoop/Variants/FolderNameVaries/file1.tsv"
```

Comment: Yes, the `path` argument does not support wildcards.

Comment: Hmm. I see. How would we then specify the path when the actually directory names changes between inputs?

Comment: Move input_files into pattern. Show some example folder/file names to get more direct answer.

Comment: This may be easier with [fs::dir_ls](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/fs/versions/1.6.1/topics/dir_ls) which recognizes wildcards.

Comment: @dipetkov No, `fs::dir_ls` behaves exactly like `list.files` in this regard. It supports globs for *filtering*, which corresponds to the `pattern` argument of `list.files`.

Comment: Think I found a solution using the dir-function with recursive = T

Comment: @KonradRudolph I apologize for being unclear. By "may be easier with `fs`" I meant that in my experience this package simplifies file system operations over base R. So it may be a good idea to know about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List files with file pattern, and recursively:

```
x <- list.files(path = "./Unzipped/", pattern = "*.tsv", recursive = TRUE)

#it should return something like this:
x <- c("./Unzipped/FolderLoop1/Variants/FolderNameVaries/file11.tsv",
       "./Unzipped/FolderLoop2/Variants/FolderNameVaries/file22.tsv",
       "./Unzipped/FolderLoop3/Variants/FolderNameVaries/file33.tsv")
```

Then use *regex* to match folders:

```
grep("FolderLoop1", x, value = TRUE, fixed = TRUE)
# [1] "./Unzipped/FolderLoop1/Variants/FolderNameVaries/file11.tsv"
```

Comment: The recursion + grep two-step approach has the unintended side effect that it will match both `FolderLoop1/Variants/FolderNameVaries/file11.tsv` and `FolderLoop3/Variants/FolderLoop1/file33.tsv` should that second file exist.

Comment: @dipetkov of course, this is not the solution, just an idea, they can improve the regex to match their problem.